# Click Event Works Only For Last Marker

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have multiple markers on a map. The click event only works for one marker, probably the last marker "loaded" on the map. It calls a C# method and it works but only on the last marker. Other markers don't cause the event and call the method. I wondered if any one could help? Below is the code for the html (actually PHP) page and then the C# code. I think I need to modify the Goolge Maps code but have tried many things with no luck.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 

    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.9/src/markerwithlabel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
    html, body { padding: 0; margin: 0 }
   .labels {
         color: red;
         background-color: white;
         font-family: "Verdana", "Arial", sans-serif;
         font-size: 10px;
         font-weight: bold;
         text-align: center;
         width: 50px;     
         border: 1px solid black;
         white-space: nowrap;
   }
    </style>

</head> 
<body> 
    <?php
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","realestate_db"); 
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();}
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `ID`, `lat` , `long` FROM `house` ");
    ?>

    <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div> 

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        var pt;
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { 
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP });
        var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
                pt =  new google.maps.LatLng( <?php echo $row['lat'] . "," . $row['long']; ?> );
                 marker = new  MarkerWithLabel({ 
                    position: pt,  
                    map: map, 
                    title: 'House',
                    labelContent: "House " + <?php echo $row['ID'] ?> ,
                    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(-10, 50),
                    labelClass: "labels",
                    labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75}
               });
               markerBounds.extend(pt);
        <?php } 

              mysqli_close($con); 

        ?>

        map.fitBounds(markerBounds);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) { 
        window.external.GetApplicationName(); });



    </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

the C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace houseDB1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting  = new ExternalApplication();
        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate("127.0.0.1/box3.php");
        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted_1(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        [ComVisible(true)]
        public class ExternalApplication
        {
            public void GetApplicationName()
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ZZTOP");
                //return "The application";
            }
        }



    }


}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that's because you only added `click` listener to the last `MarkerWithLabel` object referenced by `marker` variable.

Try to move the following piece of code inside the `while` block, so that the listener added for every `MarkerWithLabel` instance created in each iteration :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) { 
        window.external.GetApplicationName(); });
```

Comment: Yes,it worked. Makes perfect sense now that I see it. I can even pass parameters/data back to the C#. There's some nice "internal book keeping" going on with these events and function calls.  Thanks so much!